# How to disable the javascript security warning in a webbrowser control?

Tags: vba, ms-access

My webbrowser control is working with dynamic webpages. They are created with

```
 Webbrowser0.Object.Document.Open
 Webbrowser0.Object.Document.write "..."
 Webbrowser0.Object.Document.Close
```

Now I have following problem: When I do it like that the mouse pointer is flickering and javascript works. When I put a simple "DoEvents" before the .Open the mouse pointer does not flicker, but I get this annoying IE security warning that prevents javascript being executed.

I've tried to add a "`<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->`", but this does not change anything.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks found a solution per try-and-error. Setting the initial Control Source to "about: blank" works perfectly and does not need internet connection.